# How to retrieve air price after PNR creation through GetReservationRQ on Sabre API?

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I'm trying to create a PNR without actually booking it. The idea is to create the PNR to temporarily "block" the price until the time limit is reached. This way, the user can continue searching for other flights without worrying this price will be gone.

I'm able to create the PNR without problems and it returns the AirPrice, but when i retrieve the PNR through GetReservationRQ, i can see the flight details + passengers, but the AirPrice is gone.

How can i get it again ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain the price you are actually "booking" the flights - your are just not ticketing/fulfilling them.

I dont know what workflow you are using, but you should call the enhanchedairbook + passengerdetails.

If you then get a PNR Locator to retrieve you can call it with GetreservationsRQ. Everything is retained now for at least end of the day with the price you gave. Airlines usually require you to reprice the pnr before issuing to have a daily accurate pricing on it.

If you then want to ticket/fulfill them you call the according api function or queue it to your ticketing partner. If the creation day was before the day of this you need to reprice and save the price to the pnr

Answer (score 1):

You can retain the pricing response with a PQ using Retain="true" in your OTA_AirPriceRQ call. You could save the price quote and then read that again whenever you want.